# Java android send picture to server, how I can create a frame?

Tags: java, android, image, upload, dataformat

How I can create frame which look like this:

```
0xB (byte)
0xA (byte)
0xA (byte)
0xD (byte)
width img (short)
height picture (short)
size img in byte  (int)
Binary data PICTURE
0xB (byte)
0xE (byte)
0xE (byte)
0xF (byte)
```

I don't know how I can create this frame.

A width and height `img` I get just like this:

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

Here I get the size:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapOrg;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems You need `Socket` [connection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). Something like this (after your code ):

```
Socket clientSocket;

clientSocket = new Socket(<address_of_server>, <number_of_port>);

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeByte((byte)0xB);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xA);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xA);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xD);
dos.writeShort(width);
dos.writeShort(height);
dos.writeInt(lengthbmp);
dos.write(imageInByte);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xB);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xE);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xE);
dos.writeByte((byte)0xF);
...
clientSocket.close();
```

You can google more `Socket` connection examples, for example [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).

**Update**

You also can use sockets to send strings to your server:

```
clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SOCKET_SERVERPORT);

dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF("Hello");
dos.writeUTF("World!");
...
```

And You should do it in separate (not UI) thread. Full example is something like that:

```
class SocketClientThread implements Runnable {
        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String strResponseData;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("<address>");
                clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, <port_number>);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                // now you can write data to stream
                dos.writeUTF("Hello");
                dos.writeUTF("World!");

                // you can also read data from stream
                strResponseData = dis.readUTF();


            } catch (UnknownHostException ignore) {
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }

            finally{
                if (clientSocket != null){
                    try {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And than You can use `SocketClientThread` this way:

```
Thread socketClientThread;
socketClientThread = new Thread(new SocketClientThread());
socketClientThread.start();
```

Comment: Andriy Omelchenko  could you exmplain me how I can send using a Socket ?

Comment: First of all your server should can process `socket` connection. In this case You can create upload stream and write bytes to it according your data format. [Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html) is other good example.

Comment: Ok but for example I want to send a string "Hello world" in byte and I don't know how I can modyf this example for do this. Could you help me ?

Comment: Ok but I don't know how I can send this You give me a example link : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html  how I can add something and send ?